# Using GoogleMaps-like buttons in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, zooming

I would like to use such buttons

[image]

instead of classical buttons drawn by `tkinter`:

```
Tk.Button(root, text = "Moveup", command=moveup).place(x=10,y=10)
Tk.Button(root, text = "Movedown", command=movedown).place(x=10,y=40)
Tk.Button(root, text = "Moveleft", command=moveleft).place(x=10,y=70)
Tk.Button(root, text = "Moveright", command=moveright).place(x=10,y=100)
```

**What's the cleaner way to do this ?** (I have seen dirty solutions with widgets overlapping but I'm not sure it's the best solution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any buttons in situations like this, when more easily you could use [**events and bindings**](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

provided the image:

[image]

To detect if it was the `up,down,right or left` arrow clicked in the above image you could check if it was within the range of that certain part of the image:

---

*Finally The Code:*

```
import Tkinter as Tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x360+100+50")
canvas = Tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.grid(sticky=Tk.N+Tk.E+Tk.S+Tk.W)

width = 300
height = 180

image_file = Image.open("above_image.png")
PIL_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_file.convert("RGBA"))
canvas_img = canvas.create_image(width,height,image=PIL_image)

def callback(event):
    """ This function is called whenever a event occurs """
    if width-9 < event.x < width+9 and height-24 < event.y < height-12:
        print "clicked up arrow!"
    elif width-9 < event.x < width+9 and height+12 < event.y < height+24:
        print "clicked down arrow!"
    elif width+12 < event.x < width+25 and height-8 < event.y < height+8:
        print "clicked right arrow!"
    elif width-25 < event.x < width-12 and height-8 < event.y < height+8:
        print "clicked left arrow!"

canvas.bind("<Button-1>", callback)
root.mainloop()
```